# Integrating tomcat to siteminder

Tags: tomcat, siteminder

Is there a detailed guide for using Siteminder with Tomcat .I searched over Google and SO most of the questions were unanswered for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the direct link to the Tomcat and JBoss application server agent download with pdf.

https://support.ca.com/irj/portal/phpdocs?filePath=7/5262/Integration_for_CA_Single_Sign-On_with_Tomcat_2.7.zip

or you can search on "CA SiteMinder Application Server Agent for Tomcat" on their support site.

-also-

Here's an open source implementation, although it appears to be based on filters and not Valves which it probably should be.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150405034132/http://www.tony007.com/netegrity.htm

You could write your own JAAS provider.  I've done this before and it's not too hard.
( see http://www.kopz.org/public/documents/tomcat/jaasintomcat.html )

I've also written a custom Valve implementation as well for integrating with a different SSO system.  It's not as straightforward and i had issues in geronimo with class loading.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to put an Apache Web Server in front of Tomcat and setup apache as a reverse proxy to pass traffic to Tomcat.  You would need to install the CA SiteMinder Web Agent for Apache, but a Tomcat agent would not be needed since you would be passing all the traffic through Apache.